# Flutter Timer.periodic register/run once

Tags: flutter, timer, runonce

i would like to have a Timer runing once in main.dart to check user activity

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    initPlatformState();
    _fetchMasterData("a", "b");
    _startActivityTimer();
  }

  bool _activityTimerRunning = false;
  void _startActivityTimer() {
    if (!_activityTimerRunning) {
      Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) {
        _timerTicked(timer);

        setState(() {
          _activityTimerRunning = true;
        });
        print("Timer started");
      });
    }
  }
```

But initState gets called more than once, so it is not the right place to register the timer. Where should it be placed?

Comment: initstate can't be called more than once. can you add more information what is actually happening and what you want.

Comment: your are right! initState is called only once. The problem with the code above is that the print statement is in the wrong place and its executed every time the timer ticks! See the corrected code in my anser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample code.

```
int start =  5;
fName(){
    Timer _timer;
    const oneSecond = Duration(seconds: 5);
        _timer = Timer.periodic(
          oneSecond,
            (Timer timer) => setState((){
              if(start == 0)
                timer.cancel();
              else{
               _activityTimerRunning = true;
               start -= 1;
              }
            })
          );
}
```

When you want to start you timer, call fName() method, after that timer can started. So and also you can check condition, when

`if(start != 0){
...
}`

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question has i silly mistake, the print statement is in the wrong place. Here is the working code:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    initPlatformState();
    _fetchMasterData("a", "b");
    _startActivityTimer();
  }

  void _startActivityTimer() {
    print("Timer started");
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) {
      _timerTicked(timer);
    });
  }
```

"TimerStarted" get executed only once